# Python parse an xml file pass result to array

Tags: python, arrays, xml, parsing

I am attempting to parse an xml file which I have accomplished and pass the results into an array which will be used later on. The xml is opened read and parsed where I am picking out 3 elements (channel, start and title). As shown in code below, the start is date and time. I am able to split date and time and store in date. As the code loops thru each xml entry I would like to pick out the channel, start and title and store to a multidimensional array. I have done this in Brightscript but can't understand the array or list structure of Python. Once I have all entries in the array or list, I will need to parse that array pulling out all titles and dates with the same date. Can somebody guide me thru this?

```
xmldoc=minidom.parse (xmldoc)
programmes= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("programme")
def getNodeText(node):
    nodelist = node.childNodes
    result = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            result.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(result)

title = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
#print("Node Name : %s" % title.nodeName)
#print("Node Value : %s \n" % getNodeText(title))
programmes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("programme")

for programme in programmes:
    cid = programme.getAttribute("channel")
    starts=programme.getAttribute("start")
    cutdate=starts[0:15]
    year= int(cutdate[0:4])
    month= int(cutdate[5:6])
    day= int(cutdate[7:8])
    hour= int(cutdate[9:10])
    minute= int(cutdate[11:12])
    sec= int(cutdate[13:14])
    date=datetime(year, month, day,hour, minute, sec)
    title = programme.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
    print("id:%s, title:%s, starts:%s" %
          (cid, getNodeText(title), starts))
    print (date)
```

Comment: Can you share input xml file with us? or email me on vivekbsable@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python normally refers to arrays as `list`s and it looks like what you want is a list of lists (there's an `array` module and the whole `numpy` extension with its own arrays, but it doesn't look like you want that:-).

So start the desired list as empty:

```
results = []
```

and where you now just print things, append them to the list:

```
results.append([cid, getNodeText(title), date])
```

(or whatever -- your indentation is so rambling it would cause tons of syntax errors in Python and confuses me about what exactly you want:-).

Now for the part

> I will need to parse that array pulling out all titles and dates with
>   the same date

just sort the results by date:

```
import operator

results.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

then group by that:

```
import itertools

for date, items in itertools.groupby(results, operator.itemgetter(2)):
    print(date,[it[1] for it in items])
```

or whatever else you want to do with this grouping.

You could improve this style in many ways but this does appear to give you the key functionality you're asking for.